# How to paste plain text in a Quill-based editor

Tags: editor, rich-text-editor, quill

Quill (https://quilljs.com/) makes it simple to embed a quality text editor in a web page. When pasting html content in the editor, it filters the pasted html and then puts it into the text editor. My question is: How can I configure Quill so it pastes only plain text in the text editor? It would filter out all tags and leave the plain text only.

The documentation about the Clipboard module (http://quilljs.com/docs/modules/clipboard/) says that it is possible to add custom Matchers to the Clipboard, that will kind of filter the pasted text.

I don't know how to write a matcher that only allows plain text. Any help and any examples are much appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After trial and error, I found the answer. The following matcher will cause the editor to paste plain text only:

```
quill.clipboard.addMatcher (Node.ELEMENT_NODE, function (node, delta) {
    var plaintext = $ (node).text ();
    return new Delta().insert (plaintext);
});
```

It uses jQuery. :)

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing using removeFormat()

Comment: @Natim please try it, would be great :)

Comment: I would but I am having a hard time finding out the range from the delta I get in the paste event.

Comment: why pasting into Natim's example <b>bbb</b> doesnt work(I use ctrl+v)? It shows string with tags?

Answer (score 11):

Couldn't get the answer to work. Here's another method that patches the clipboard module to accept plain text only.

GitHub Gist:

https://gist.github.com/prodrammer/d4d205594b2993224b8ad111cebe1a13

Clipboard implementation:

```
import Quill from 'quill'
const Clipboard = Quill.import('modules/clipboard')
const Delta = Quill.import('delta')

class PlainClipboard extends Clipboard {
  onPaste (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const range = this.quill.getSelection()
    const text = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
    const delta = new Delta()
    .retain(range.index)
    .delete(range.length)
    .insert(text)
    const index = text.length + range.index
    const length = 0
    this.quill.updateContents(delta, 'silent')
    this.quill.setSelection(index, length, 'silent')
    this.quill.scrollIntoView()
  }
}

export default PlainClipboard
```

Example usage:

```
import Quill from 'quill'
import PlainClipboard from './PlainClipboard'

Quill.register('modules/clipboard', PlainClipboard, true)
```

Comment: What is this.quill in PlainClipboard? How do I get this.quill in PlainClipboard?

Comment: It's inherited from the Clipboard class provided by quill. Not sure if this changed. I use quill version 1.3.6.

Comment: @RyanHaney I got null value for this.quill.getSelection(). Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: @susmitarai Are you using quill 1.3.6? I'm not sure what it would take to get it working in quill 1.3.7.

Comment: Hello @RyanHaney, I was able to paste the plan text in editor. But whenever I save it , the text doesn't get save. Seems like the pasted content is not bonded with the editor while saving

Answer (score 8):

Updated solution of [teusbenschop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41238013/2424880) - works without jQuery and also fix problem with missing Delta object.

```js
quill.clipboard.addMatcher (Node.ELEMENT_NODE, function (node, delta) {
    var plaintext = node.innerText
    var Delta = Quill.import('delta')
    return new Delta().insert(plaintext)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

For the googlers;

I created a Quill plugin, that removes all tags and attributes that are not supported. Unless otherwise configured it detects that by looking into the toolbar module.

I thought I post it here so others will not have to struggle :)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/quill-paste-smart

Comment: unfortunately it keeps giving me `quill-paste-smart.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function at l.value` error

Comment: Strange. could you [create an issue](https://github.com/Artem-Schander/quill-paste-smart/issues)? A reproduction sandbox would also help

Comment: I created an issue in Git Hub. You can check out this [codepen](https://codepen.io/coolIgetit/pen/NWoyJrd)

Answer (score 1):

All the proposed options either didn't work for me or broke the logic of keyboard input. It was a decision for me

```
quill.on('text-change', function (delta, oldDelta, source) {
    if (source === 'paste') {
        var text = quill.getText();
        quill.setText(text);
    }
});
```

When changing the text, we check the resource, and if it is 'paste', we extract the text without formatting and set it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Quill from 'quill';

quill.clipboard.addMatcher(Node.ELEMENT_NODE, function (node, delta) {
  const plaintext = node.innerText
  const Delta = Quill.import('delta')
  return new Delta().insert(plaintext)
});
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?