# How to enforce a formatting on paste?

Tags: quill

I found how to [strip any existing formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55026088/441662) from pasted content, but I didn't find a graceful way to enforce a format to it.

I use the current hack:

```js
quill.clipboard.addMatcher (Node.ELEMENT_NODE, (node, delta) => {
    quill.format('header', 1); // <-- hacky sneaky set format in quill
    return new Delta().insert(node.innerText); // <-- returns stripped text
});
```

Although this works, what is the appropriate way to set a format before text is added by pasting? I suspect I need to register an event handler or hook somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simpler than I thought:

```js
quill.clipboard.addMatcher (Node.ELEMENT_NODE, (node, delta) => {
    // return stripped and reformatted text
    return new Delta().insert(node.innerText).insert('\n', { header: 1 });
});
```

The trick is to utilize the Delta DSL properly. It didn't realize at first how header formatting works with that weird newline approach, but it seems that's just how Quill works.